# Does the given symmetry help to prove that the region in which conditions $\textbf{cond.1}$ and $\textbf{cond.2}$ hold is the same?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, solution-verification, symmetric-functions

I have two conditions $\textbf{cond.1}$ and  $\textbf{cond.2}$ for two variables $x,y\in(0,2\pi)$

$$  \text{cond.1}:=\qquad f_2<f_1<f_3  $$
$$  \text{cond.2}:=\qquad g_2<g_1<g_3  $$

where the functions $f_i$ and $g_i$, $i=1,2,3$ are as follows
$$  f_1=3 \cos (5 x+y)+13 \cos (y) $$
$$  f_2=3 \cos (9 x-y)-2 \cos (7 x+y) $$
$$  f_3=\sin ^2(x) $$
and
$$  g_1= 3 \cos (x+5 y)-13 \sin (x) $$
$$  g_2= 2 \cos (x+7 y)-3 \cos (x-9 y) $$
$$  g_3=\cos ^2(y) $$

**Question.** I plot the conditions $\textbf{cond.1}$ and  $\textbf{cond.2}$ and the result is as the picture below. Numerically, I see that the blue area in both plots is the same. I want to make sure about this fact analytically. On the other hand, I see that all the functions $f_i$ and $g_i$ are symmetric with respect to the exchange of $y \to x+\frac{\pi}2$; does this symmetry help to prove that the blue area in both plots is the same?

[image]

Comment: There is slightly more stuff involved in that. The symmetry will help you prove that the cond.1 area on $[0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi]$ is equal to the cond.2 area on $[\pi/2,5\pi/2]\times[-\pi/2,3\pi/2]$. Then you use *periodicity* of cond.2 (with period $2\pi$ in both $x$ and $y$) to further prove that the previous area equals the area for cond.2 on $[0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What did you mean by "previous area"?

Comment: The area for cond.2 on $[\pi/2,5\pi/2]\times[-\pi/2,3\pi/2]$

Comment: Thanks again; so, this is a proof, and now, I am sure about this equality of the areas.